# API Integration using OAuth1.0, using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

This is the API:

```
http://api.seatseller.travel/availabletrips?source=3&destination=6&doj=2013-01-9   
ConsumerKey :*****************  
ConsumerSecret : ******************
```

by this api using ajax I’m sending the response.

that url is from postman in that it is working fine but when executing through code is showing an error as follows:

["Error: OAUTH verification failed."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdGZY.png)

Comment: What is the question? Post your code not screenshots of it.

Comment: app.post('/bussbmt',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
  request('http://api.seatseller.travel/availabletrips?oauth_consumer_key=**************************&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp='+time+'&oauth_nonce=oXEOSP&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=*******************=&source='+req.body.source+'&destination='+req.body.destination+'&doj='+req.body.date+'', function (error, response) {
    var x2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
  console.log(x2);
  //return false;
  res.json(x2);
})
})

Comment: before when i trying to post my code it is not allowing, so kept a screen shot.

Comment: What does it look like when you are sending it via Postman? Where are you adding the token details? In the query params or as a header?

Comment: In postman i'm giving the Authorisation as type as auth1.0 and giving the consumer key and consumer secret.

Comment: Have you looked at the [request module](https://github.com/request/request) to ensure that you are constructing the request correctly? There is an OAuth section that might be useful.